# C++ Loss of saved variable data in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm using a linked list in order to store user input and then use their input for a calculation. When I try to use the linked list, debugging shows the list is empty.

The first function is the constructor for the House object and it creates a Room linked list that stores the length and width of a room.

```
House::House(){

    int tempwid = 0;
    int templen = 0;
    houseSize = 0;
    bool cont = true;

    node *root; 
    node *conductor;  

    root = new node;
    root->next = 0;

    conductor = root;

    if (conductor != 0) {
        while (cont){

            houseSize++;
            tempwid = 0;
            templen = 0;

            if(tempwid == -1 || templen == -1){
                cont = false;
            }//End if

            else{

                cout << "\nPlease enter the dimensions for room #" << houseSize << ". Enter a -1 when you are finished.";
                cout << "\nWidth? ";
                cin >> tempwid; 
                cout << "Length? ";
                cin >> templen; 

                if(tempwid == -1 || templen == -1){
                    cont = false;
                }//End if

                else{
                    conductor->width=tempwid;
                    conductor->length=templen;  

                    conductor->next = new node;
                    conductor = conductor->next;
                    conductor->next = 0;

                }//End else

            }//End else
        }//End while

        conductor->next = new node;  
        conductor = conductor->next;
        conductor->next = 0;       

    }//End if

}//End constructor
```

This function will just take the length and width of all the rooms and figure out the area of the total house.

```
double House :: calculateTax(double tax){

    node *root; 
    node *conductor;  

    double totalArea = 0;
    int i = 0;

    conductor = root;

    while (conductor->next!=0){
        cout <<"Length: " << conductor->length;
        cout <<"Width: " << conductor->width;

        totalArea += conductor->length * conductor->width;

        conductor = conductor->next;

    }//End while

    totalArea *= tax;
    return totalArea;

}//End Function
```

Comment: Your linked list has **one** room in it? If that is the case you can expect `while (conductor->next!=0)` to be false immediately. That should be `while (conductor)`. And `node *root;` has no business being declared locally in *either* `House::House` or `calculateTax` at all. That decl is hiding the member variable `root`. (there *is* a member variable `root`, *right* )?

Answer (score 3):

You are using local variables `root` and `conductor` in both methods, as opposed to class members. You did not provide the class declaration to see if such members are present at all, but even if they are, they are shadowed with the local variables using the same names. The values of local variables are not shared between different functions and methods, and between different invocations of the same function/method. This is why they are called *local*.